# How to modify data in an External data base connection using excel as a front-end

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel front end which connects to a number of data sources. I would like changes made to the data using the front end, to update the source. How do i do this? The connections are to locally stored workbooks. They will eventually move to network stored workbooks which others can modify directly.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably a connection string. Then use some SQL queries. Although I have not tried it myself. My co-worker does it all the time - update a front-end workbook then then update another workbook automatically by VBA.

Source: https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/